# Cache Whole Site With CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to cache whole site with CloudFront with ELB and EC2 as a backend. Response header for url I always get miss from X-Cache :

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Cache-Control:public
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:12501
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 08 Sep 2015 07:16:56 GMT
Expires:Tue, 08 Sep 2015 07:16:56 GMT
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 e5f2e8167f4cb891927a3b8ab905bfaf.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront
```

The config webserver (Nginx) :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name somedomain.com www.somedomain.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass_header $Set_Cookie;

        location ~ / {
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                expires 0;
                proxy_pass http://my_stream;
        }
}
```

Object caching for default (*) behaviour at cloudfront I'm using costumize with :

```
Minimum TTL 200
Maximum TTL 400
Default TTL 320
```

and whitelist for headers is :

```
Host
CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer
CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer
CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer
```

If I'm pointing directly file e.g: http://somedomain.com/a_file.php, I'll get X-Cache : Hit for next refresh. But if only http://somedomain I only get X-Cache : Miss from cloudfront

Is there something miss with my config ?

Answer (score 1):

The CloudFront min/max/default ttls don't override what your origin server appears to be returning:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

This overrides all the defaults.

> To change the cache duration for an individual object, you can configure your origin to add a `Cache-Control max-age` or `Cache-Control s-maxage` directive, or an `Expires` header field to the object.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Comment: so i should set expires on nginx config ?

Comment: Certainly not.  The gist of my answer is that *CloudFront isn't caching the page because your server is telling CloudFront not to.*  You need to understand where that `Cache-Control: max-age=0` is coming from (code? framework?), and fix the problem at the correct place.